# Craft CMS: Data too long for column 'cacheKey' at row 1

Tags: craft3, database, cache

We have Craft CMS v3 using multi-sites.

We are using cache to cache whole pages based on the absolute URL as some URLs have query parameters which seem to be ignored when not using a key.  So the absoluteUrl is working. Our cache code is:

```
{% cache using key craft.app.request.absoluteUrl unless craft.app.request.getSegment(1) == 'members' or craft.app.request.getSegment(1) == 'data-summary' %}
```

One of the sites, Korean, has a few pages that result in an Internal Server Error as follows.

```
Next Twig\Error\RuntimeError: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'cacheKey' at row 1
```

This leads me to believe the URL is longer than 255 characters as the database column templatecaches.cacheKey is varchar(255).

The SQL is:

```
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `templatecaches` (`cacheKey`, `siteId`, `path`, `expiryDate`, `body`) VALUES ('https://www.mydomain.com/ko/%C3%AC%C2%86%C2%8C%C3%AA%C2%B0%C2%9C/%C3%AC%C2%9D%C2%B8%C3%AC%C2%A6%C2%9D-%C3%AB%C2%B0%C2%8F-%C3%AC%C2%88%C2%98%C3%AC%C2%83%C2%81-%C3%AB%C2%82%C2%B4%C3%AC%C2%97%C2%AD/%C3%AC%C2%B5%C2%9C%C3%AA%C2%B3%C2%A0-%C3%AA%C2%B8%C2%B0%C3%AC%C2%97%C2%85-%C3%AC%C2%88%C2%98%C3%AC%C2%83%C2%81?__geom=%E2%9C%AA', 26, 'site:ìê°/ì¸ì¦-ë°-ìì-ë´ì­/ìµê³ -ê¸°ì-ìì', '2020-11-16 18:41:26', '[all the page content here]')"). in /home/mydomain/craftcms/templates/_layout.twig:84
```

The page URL in the browser has Korean symbols of course, so I guess its too many characters once converted to ascii.

I tried changing it to a Longtext as per another similar issue with a different column, but MySQL will not allow it due to the cacheKey being in the index.

Recommended solutions were to remove the column from the index but to be honest I dont want to start messing with things like this without guidance from Craft.

Is there a Craft recommended approach to this issue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a Craft recommended approach to this issue please?

The simplest solution would be to update to Craft 3.5+

Template cache data went from being stored in the database to the file system, so this won't be an issue for you anymore.

Comment: Oh right, good. Had not updated yet as its a troublesome task due to composer problems every time we want to update. I’ll give it a go as I get other issues relating to the database size from template caches.

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks a lot! The update went OK too... its just previously and on a cloned site we have issues with Composer errors so I am often reluctant to update. But was OK this time and all seems to work. Hope this also reduces the DB size from from 10Gb!